# How can i add variable to result of $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

i need to add a variable to get result of my $.getJSON. I think if you see the Problem yiu know what i mean. It is not a big Problem i think my syntax is not correct. But i dont know how i can handle this.

```
function get_status() {
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    $.getJSON('https://api.verystream.com/file/info?file=' + verystream_ids[i], function(data) { 
      var text = `Date: ${data.result.` + verystream_ids[i] + `.name}<br>`
      alert(text);
    });
  }
}
```

My problem is now here:

```
var text = `Date: ${data.result.` + verystream_ids[i] + `.name}<br>`
```

I need to add this variable `verystream_ids[i]` to my `data.result.$VARIABLE$.name` to get results. How can I add the variable correctly?

Here is a Picture of the JSON.
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLJQP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1):

To access the keys of an object by a variable you need to use bracket notation:

```
var text = `Date: ${data.result[verystream_ids[i]].name}<br>`;
```

Comment: is not working. Error: TypeError: data.result[verystream_ids[i]] is undefined.

Comment: Could you edit the question to give an example of what the value of `data` and `verystream_ids` is